# USB mouse not recognized after restoring to factory settings

Tags: windows-10, usb, mouse, system-restore, factory-defaults

I've recently had to restore my computer back to factory settings (all applications removed and configuration resetted but keeping my files) after a Windows 10 update failed to install properly. My mouse did not work ever since (I tried both a cabled and a wireless mouse). What's odd is that the USB ports work perfectly fine with other devices. The touchpad works fine, though

I tried to have a look at mouse configuration but I cannot see anything that could help my computer recognize it. It just ascts as if it wasn't there. What other ressources do I have to try to solve the problem?

Comment: so it's two devices (wired and wireless)? does come up in the device manager? does the mouse still work on other computers?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "mouse configuration"?

Comment: @Albin Indeed. Those mouses are working fine on other computers. By "mouse configuration", I mean the options that come in Windows' settings screen

Comment: what about the device manager?

Comment: @Albin unfortunately it's completely unaware that my mouse is connected

Comment: How do you make sure it doesn't show up? It's easy to miss it in the device manager. With PowerShell `wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'USB%'" get /value` you can list all your USB devices. Or you can use `msinfo32`, but there you need to know the category.